# How to access an attribute from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class

Let's say I have this example program:

```
class whatever:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.stuff = []
    
    def __str__(self):
        return ...

class whenever:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

If I want to use 'self.stuff' in the class 'whenever', how would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: the same way *you always access an attribute from an instance*, using *the instance*. i.e. `w = whatever(1,2)` then `w.stuff`

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instance, then you could just do:

```py
my_whatever = whatever(0, 0)
print(my_whatever.stuff)
```

So if you want to do this from class `whenever`, you could do something like:

```py
class whenever:
    def __init__(self, a, b, w):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
        self.whatever = w
```

or:

```py
class whenever:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

        self.whatever = whatever(0, 0)
```

and then access it like:

```py
print(self.whatever.stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think inheritance can help in your case.
Make `whatever` the parent class and `whenever` the child class. Then use the `super()` method in child class to initialise the parent class variable.

In this way you can call all the methods and variables in `whatever` from `whenever`

Additionally, You might also want to pass the required values for arguments (x,y) in `whenever`

```
class whatever:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.stuff = []

    def __str__(self):
        return ...


class whenever(whatever):
    def __init__(self, a, b, x, y):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        # you can access like this as whenever's own variable
        # print(self.stuff)

# you have to pass the init variables for whatever also
# Here 3,4 is x,y 
whenever_object  = whenever(1,2,3,4)
print(whenever_object.stuff)
```